# Relative clauses by using to-infinitive

Tags: relative-clauses

What is the difference between these 2 clauses?:

> 1.-I've just seen a friend **that** I know since 20 years ago.
>
> 2.-I've just seen a fríend me **to** know since 20 years ago.

Comment: Uh, the second one isn't English, while the first one is? And neither of them are complete sentences. Your question seems to lack crucial context required for answering it. [To prevent wrong and incorrect answers, please include more details](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/) of where you've encountered this or attempt to use it. Otherwise, this question may get closed. See also [What should I do when I saw a phrase or sentence I don't understand?](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1084/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second sentence in incorrect but might be changed to

> A friend known ***to*** me.

Edit to reflect change in OP's question

> I've just seen a friend ***known*** to me for 20 years.
>   I've just seen a friend I ***have known*** for 20 years.  *(this is more usual phrasing)*

which has the same meaning as

> A friend **that** I know.